# Tab background click effect and selected tab background color change

Tags: android, xml

I want to implement both click effect and selected tab background, I use the below code to change the selected tab background.

myLayout.xml code

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            />
```

tab_color_selector inside drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/colorTabPrimary" 
 android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
 </selector>
```

the above code works perfectly,

To provide click effect I have to use the below

```
 app:tabBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

How can I combine both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

tab_color_selector.xml drawable add ripple.xml to state_pressed

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/blue_selected_tab" 
 android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ripple" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</selector>
```

ripple.xml drawable

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:color="@color/blue_selected_tab"
tools:targetApi="lollipop"> <!-- ripple effect color -->
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/blue_selected" /> <!-- background color -->
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

For changing the `textColor` of selected tab you can simply use property of `TabLayout`.

```
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
```

to change the background of selected tab do following

```
app:tabBackground="@drawable/selector_tab"
```

Create one xml file

selector_tab.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorGreen" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_selected="false">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: thank you for the response. I need to implement both click effect and selected tab background color. is there any way to do so?